# posting url in bibliography in overleaf as reference

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, back-referencing

I have to post a link to this website https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/tutorial-shadow-it
as a reference, I am using in my documentation. I see in my template in overleaf I wrote in the file
BIBeusflat2019.bib

```
@misc{microsoft,
 author =
 title =Discover and manage shadow IT in your network
 url ="https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/tutorial-shadow-it"
}
```

but then when I compile the pdf I do not get the url as reference link in pdf . I am using a template here
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx

So how do I post a link to URL in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the .cls file of the template

and change

```
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
```

to

```
\RequirePackage{graphicx, hyperref, url}
```

this adds the required packages.   Now go to the .bib file an add your entry as

```
@misc{microsoft,
author = {Microsoft},
title = {Discover and manage shadow IT in your network},
howpublished = "\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/tutorial-shadow-it}"
}
```

now you can cite this ref in your .tex using

```
\cite{microsoft}
```

Comment: Thanks I need to do similar things in this template https://www.overleaf.com/read/zscvvsxbqphw
 this is some custom template which is given to me by some one. Please tell in which file I need to do similar thing so that I can cite urls in my references.